# Surface plot for multivariate 5 degree polynomial regression in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, non-linear-regression, numerical-analysis

I am implementing a paper in Python, which was originally implemented in MATLAB. The paper says that a five degree polynomial was found using curve fitting from a set of sampling data points. I did not want to use their polynomial, so I started using the sample data points (given in paper) and tried to find a 5 degree polynomial using sklearn Polynomial Features and linear_model. As it is a multivariate equation f(x,y) where x and y are the length and width of a certain pond and f is the initial concentration of pollutant.

So my problem is that sklearn Polynomial Features transforms the test and train data points into n-polynomial points (I think as far as I understood it). However when I need the **clf.predict** function (where clf is the trained model) to take only the x and y values because when I am drawing the surface graph from Matplotlib, it requires meshgrid, so when I meshgrid my sklean-transformed test points, it's shape becomes like NxN whereas the predict function requires Nxn (where n is the number of degrees of polynomial in which it transformed  the data) and N is the number of rows.

Is there any possible way to draw the mesh points for this polynomial?

Paper Link: http://www.ajer.org/papers/v5(11)/A05110105.pdf
Paper title: Mathematical Model of Biological Oxygen Demand in Facultative Wastewater Stabilization Pond Based on Two-Dimensional
Advection-Dispersion Model

If possible, please look at the figure 5 and 6 in the paper (link above). This is what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you
`enter code here`

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np
from operator import itemgetter
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


def model_BOD (cn):
    cnp1 = []
    n = len(cn)
    # variables:
    dmx = 1e-5
    dmy = 1e-5
    u = 2.10e-4
    v = 2.10e-4
    obs_time = 100
    dt = 0.1

    for t in np.arange(0.1,obs_time,dt):
        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(N):
                d = j + (i-1)*N
                dxp1 = d  + N
                dyp1 = d + 1
                dxm1 = d - N
                dym1 = d - 1

                cnp1.append(t*(((-2*dmx/dx**2)+(-2*dmy/dy**2)+(1/t))*cn[dxp1] + (dmx/dx**2)*cn[dyp1] \
                                + (dmy/dy**2)*cn[dym1] - (u/(2*dx))*cn[dxp1] + (u/(2*dx))*cn[dxm1] \
                                - (v/(2*dy))*cn[dyp1] + (v/(2*dy))*cn[dym1]))
        cn = cnp1
        cnp1 = []
    return cn

N = 20
Length = 70
Width = 77
dx = Length/N
dy = Width/N

deg_of_poly = 5

datapoints = np.array([
    [12.5,70,81.32],[25,70,88.54],[37.5,70,67.58],[50,70,55.32],[62.5,70,56.84],[77,70,49.52],
    [0,11.5,71.32],[77,57.5,67.20],
    [0,23,58.54],[25,46,51.32],[37.5,46,49.52],
    [0,34.5,63.22],[25,34.5,48.32],[37.5,34.5,82.30],[50,34.5,56.42],[77,34.5,48.32],[37.5,23,67.32],
    [0,46,64.20],[77,11.5,41.89],[77,46,55.54],[77,23,52.22],
    [0,57.5,93.72],
    [0,70,98.20],[77,0,42.32]
    ])

X = datapoints[:,0:2]
Y = datapoints[:,-1]

predict_x = []
predict_y = []
for i in np.linspace(0,Width,N):
    for j in np.linspace(0,Length,N):
        predict_x.append([i,j])

predict = np.array(predict_x)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg_of_poly)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)

predict_ = poly.fit_transform(predict)
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, Y)
prediction = []

for k,i in enumerate(predict_):
    prediction.append(clf.predict(np.array([i]))[0])

prediction_ = model_BOD(prediction)
print prediction_
XX = []
XX = predict[:,0]
YY = []
YY = predict[:,-1]
XX,YY = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z = prediction
##R = np.sqrt(XX**2+YY**2)
##Z = np.tan(R)

surf = ax.plot_surface(XX,YY,Z)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the key logic here is to generate polynomial features from your meshgrid, make the prediction and plot the prediction with the original meshgrid. Hope the following gives what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn import linear_model

# The training set
datapoints = np.array([
    [12.5,70,81.32], [25,70,88.54], [37.5,70,67.58], [50,70,55.32], 
    [62.5,70,56.84], [77,70,49.52], [0,11.5,71.32], [77,57.5,67.20], 
    [0,23,58.54], [25,46,51.32], [37.5,46,49.52], [0,34.5,63.22], 
    [25,34.5,48.32], [37.5,34.5,82.30], [50,34.5,56.42], [77,34.5,48.32], 
    [37.5,23,67.32], [0,46,64.20], [77,11.5,41.89], [77,46,55.54], 
    [77,23,52.22], [0,57.5,93.72], [0,70,98.20], [77,0,42.32]
    ])
X = datapoints[:,0:2]
Y = datapoints[:,-1]
# 5 degree polynomial features
deg_of_poly = 5
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=deg_of_poly)
X_ = poly.fit_transform(X)
# Fit linear model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_, Y)

# The test set, or plotting set
N = 20
Length = 70
predict_x0, predict_x1 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, Length, N), 
                                     np.linspace(0, Length, N))
predict_x = np.concatenate((predict_x0.reshape(-1, 1), 
                            predict_x1.reshape(-1, 1)), 
                           axis=1)
predict_x_ = poly.fit_transform(predict_x)
predict_y = clf.predict(predict_x_)

# Plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 6))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
surf = ax1.plot_surface(predict_x0, predict_x1, predict_y.reshape(predict_x0.shape), 
                        rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, alpha=0.5)
ax1.scatter(datapoints[:, 0], datapoints[:, 1], datapoints[:, 2], c='b', marker='o')

ax1.set_xlim((70, 0))
ax1.set_ylim((0, 70))
fig.colorbar(surf, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
cs = ax2.contourf(predict_x0, predict_x1, predict_y.reshape(predict_x0.shape))
ax2.contour(cs, colors='k')
fig.colorbar(cs, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Luo, that just seems right. I believe I was not reshaping matrices right. Thank you again. However this is really not related to the question at all, I seem to get very different results as compare to the paper, can you tell me how can interpret the coefficients returned by trained model (clf)? I mean like a*x^2*y^1+ ... etc.. I know that the transform converts the data-points into relevant coeffs, I can not interpret the equation.

Comment: @arshh I'm sorry that my answer is not related to your question at all. You can check coefficients with `clf.coef_` and check corresponding features with `poly.get_feature_names()`. Then you should be able to figure out things like "a*x^2*y^1+ ... etc." for this specific fitting. As for why it's different from the paper and how to interpret the equation. Again, I'm sorry I don't know.

Comment: @arshh My intention is to answer your question about "Is there any possible way to draw the mesh points for this polynomial?" and try to give you something close to "figure 5 and 6". I'm not sure if I fail to understand your real question. I would suggest you post another question and maybe get a little bit more clear about what your questions are...

Comment: @Luo, Lou you misunderstood me, when I said that 'however this is really not related to the question at all'' I meant that what I am about to ask you (about the coefficients) is not related to the question I posted.

Comment: You actually gave me the answer. I was asking another question off-topic and at the same time, I was being careful by saying that it was not related to the same question. Thank you again so much :)

Comment: No worries. You are welcome. Hope you will find answers to your questions soon.