# Modelling bivariate data

Tags: python, modeling, surface, model-fitting

I am having trouble modelling some data in python. I want to improve the very crude method that I am currently using:

```
x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 130)
y = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 113)
data = np.random.rand(130, 113)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
X1 = X.flatten()
Y1 = Y.flatten()
Z1 = data.flatten()
```

With this data I am trying to fit a model:

```
A2 = np.array([X1**3, Y1**3, (X1**2)*Y1, (Y1**2)*X1, 
X1**2, Y1**2, X1*Y1, X1, Y1, X1*0+1]).T

c2, r2, rank2, s2 = np.linalg.lstsq(A2, Z1)

tst_z2 = c2[0]*(X**3) + c2[1]*(Y**3) + c2[2]*((X**2)*Y)
+ c2[3]*((Y**2)*X) + c2[4]*(X**2) + c2[5]*(Y**2) + c2[6]*(X*Y)
+ c2[7]*X + c2[8]*Y + c2[9]*X*0+1
```

The model I am using is a standard bivariate cubic polynomial where I have typed out all of the terms needed. If I want to use quartic or higher order polynomials and move to data that has three or more independent variables then this method is going to quickly become unusable.

Is there a way to streamline/generalise this method without having to write out all of the terms so that I can move to higher order polynomials?

For a bit more context into the problem, I am trying to produce a model that fits to this [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRqFl.png):

The red-orange-ish surface is my attempt at using a bivariate cubic polynomial to fit the data. If someone knows of a better way to do this I would very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Does the polynomial module in numpy help? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval2d

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd make it work with that. When I calculate the coefficients using 'np.linalg.lstsq' I still need to input an array of all the polynomial terms. How would I use _polyval2d_ to generate an input for the _lstsq_ fitting?

Comment: Okay so I should have looked harder for the answer. I found it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961034/surface-plot-for-multivariate-5-degree-polynomial-regression-in-python]